# How can I refresh the eclipse folder with another tool?

Tags: eclipse

I create a web based project with eclipse and the application server is Tomcat and everything is OK, but I have a few files in specific folder that I should change the content of these files with another development environment that it's created by myself, after I change the file's the eclipse doesn't refresh the file and therefore I must go to eclipse, select the folder, press f5 to refresh it.

My Question is that, How can I refresh that specific folder without doing these steps, for example does eclipse have specific API for refresh the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IResource.refreshLocal` to refresh a folder (or file).

One way to use this:

```java
 IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

 IContainer folder = root.getgetContainerForLocation(new Path("folder path"));

 folder.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);
```

This must be run in an Eclipse plugin.

Update:

You can tell Eclipse to refresh automatically in Preferences > General > Workspace by checking the 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' option.

There is no way to force a refresh from a program external to Eclipse.

Comment: my development environment is not a eclipse plugin, I wanna refresh it with another program as I mentioned before

Comment: Then why put `eclipse-plugin` as a tag?

Comment: sorry it's my fault and I remove it